# OpenCV 3.4 KCF tracker HOG features (C++)

Tags: opencv, video-tracking

In OpenCV 3.4 KCF tracker (C++), how can I see if HOG features are enabled and how can I set HOG related parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I see codes below [here](https://github.com/joaofaro/KCFcpp/blob/master/README.md):

```
// Create the KCFTracker object with one of the available options
KCFTracker tracker(HOG, FIXEDWINDOW, MULTISCALE, LAB);

// Give the first frame and the position of the object to the tracker
tracker.init( Rect(xMin, yMin, width, height), frame );

// Get the position of the object for the new frame
result = tracker.update(frame);
```

Now I'm looking for Python code for this :/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my question was mostly targeted to the built-in implementation of KCF in OpenCV and how can I control the hog parameters from there.